# Limit of $(1+3x)^\frac{-2}{3x^3}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I would appreciate your help solving the following, here is what I did so far:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}(1+3x)^\frac{-2}{3x^3}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}[(1+3x)^\frac{1}{3x}]^\frac{-2}{x^2}$$

And,

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}(1+3x)^\frac{1}{3x}=\lim_{t \to 0^+}(1+t)^\frac{1}{t}= e$$

So, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for every $0<x<\delta$ : $|(1+3x)^\frac{1}{3x}|< e-2$

So $(1+3x)^\frac{1}{3x}>2$

And because $0<x<\delta$ I can say that $\frac{-2}{x^2}<0$ So $[(1+3x)^\frac{1}{3x}]^\frac{-2}{x^2} \leq 2^\frac{-2}{x^2}$

From here I don't know what to do...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We need to calculate $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}(1+3x)^{-\frac{2}{3x^{3}}}$$

> The limit has the form $\lim (1+f(x))^{g(x)}$ so the trick is to use $\lim e^{\ln(1+f(x))^{g(x)}}$.

Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}(1+3x)^{-\frac{2}{3x^{3}}}&=&\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}e^{\ln(1+3x)^{-\frac{2}{3x^{3}}}}\\
&=&e^{\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\left(-\frac{2}{3x^{3}}\ln(1+3x)\right)}\\
&=&e^{-\frac{-2}{3}\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{\ln(1+3x)}{x^{3}}}\\
&=&e^{-\frac{2}{3}\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{x^{2}(3x+1)}}, \quad (\text{L'Hopital's theorem.})\\
&=&e^{-\frac{2}{3}e^{-2\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\ln(x)}}, \quad \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\ln(x)="-\infty"\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $$\boxed{\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}(1+3x)^{-\frac{2}{3x^{3}}}=0}$$

Comment: Thank you for that, unfortunately I do not know L'Hopital yet...

Comment: You can read that theorem here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: Thank you for that :D

Answer (score 0):

If
$$L=\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)} \to 1^{\infty}$$, then
$$L=\exp[\lim_{x \to a} g(x)[f(x)-1]$$
So here
$$L=\exp[\lim_{ x\to 0} \frac{-2}{3x^3} 3x]= \exp[\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-2}{3x^2}]$$
So $$L=\exp[\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-2}{3x^2}]=0$$

Comment: Thank you for that, unfortunately I do not familiar with that yet...